# Can I get disk(partitions) infomation from Linux without commands?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to read disk(partition) infomations from /proc or /sys, or other path. Just like I can read memory status from /proc/meminfo.

How can I get partition **total size**, **usage**, **file system**, **mount point** by reading /proc or /sys/class/block or other files?

No 'df', No 'lsblk', No 'fdisk', No 'mount', No Commands. Just by reading some files. Somebody said Linux "Everything is a File". So is it posible to do this?

Comment: `No 'df', No 'lsblk', No 'fdisk', No 'mount` What research did you do? Did you read the source code `df.c` `lsblk.c` `fdisk.c` and `mount.c` to see what are they using? These commands are written in C, you can learn from what they are doing. `"Everything is a File"` That everything is a file does not mean you can `read()` from everything from that file - we have `ioctl()` calls, that are called _on_ a file.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm not good at C or C++, sorry about that...But I know a bit script program like shell, python, such like this. Can't use command because sometimes when I running my script in other's Linux, 'lsblk' command not found or 'df' return non-English message. So I'm trying to read disk infomation by file such as /proc/meminfo

Comment: @KamilCuk Let me try to read that "c files". Thanks a lot bro.

Comment: What is "usage" of partition?

Answer (score 0):

[statfs](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/statfs.c#L192) is *the* system call that return information about a filesystem. See `man statfs`. `statvfs` is more standard from POSIX.

> partition total size

To read partition total size you can read partition table of the disc and parse it.

> file system

To read file system you have to *detect* it. Basically kernel does that.

> mount point

See `cat /proc/mounts`

Comment: I decide to use 'lsblk' anyway......If somebody didn't install 'lsblk', I'll stop my script. But thank you for helping me to understand Linux Disk System. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the /proc/partitions pseudo-file to get the kernel partition table as follows:

```
cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

 259        0  500107608 nvme0n1
 259        1     614400 nvme0n1p1
 259        2    1048576 nvme0n1p2
 259        3  498443264 nvme0n1p3
 252        0    7995392 zram0
```